# JasperReports Server email showing invalid link to report

Tags: email, csv, jasperserver

I am using *JasperReports Server*.

I have scheduled a report and, because it is a very large report, I have configured the email notification to not attach the csv file but rather send an email link to the report.

The problem is that when I receive the email and click on the link, the web page displays an error: "specified page not found".

The problem is that it is giving me this link:

```
http://ip_number:port_number/jasperserver/jasperservercetrunk/fileview/fileview/My_Report.csv
```

when it should be giving me this link:

```
http://ip_number:port_number/jasperserver/fileview/fileview/My_Report.csv
```

How do I remove 'jasperservercetrunk' from this url?